# Рестайлинг сайта

Tags: seo

Собираюсь в корне поменять структуру сайта, дизайн. Упадёт ли при этом позиция в яндексе, которая уже имеется?

Comment: Упадет, но не на долго! Если поменяется вид ссылок то упадет на долго и далеко. Если все старые ссылки будут иметь редирект на новые, то упадет но не на долго. Но конкретно о сроках ответить сложно!

Comment: А если ссылки вообще не поменяются, то вообще не упадёт?

Comment: @mctrane, тут еще вопрос в том как будет оптимизирован новый дизайн. Выше точно не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После изменения внутренней структуры сайта, включая дизайн, с высокой степенью вероятности результаты выдачи изменятся, но необязательно в худшую сторону. На выдачу повлияет:

1. перелинковка страниц,
2. временное или постоянное выпадение из индекса страниц,
3. запрет части страниц для робота,
4. дублирование контента,
5. и так далее.

Вопрос очень общий. Но в любом случае, даже при полностью идентичном контенте (тексте страниц), изменения в выдаче после изменения в структуре будут, а их значимость будет прямо зависеть от глубины изменений.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ.